# Как можно сверстать такое меню адаптивно?

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сверстать такое меню адаптивно на boostrap4 ? 
Пытался ничего не получилось :((

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #3b4f73;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px; }

.nav-link {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 10px 0;
  line-height: 11px;
  position: relative; }
  .nav-link:first-child {
    line-height: 30px; }
  .nav-link:nth-child(2) {
    line-height: 15px; }
  .nav-link:nth-child(3) {
    line-height: 15px; }
  .nav-link:nth-child(4) {
    line-height: 11px; }
  .nav-link:nth-child(5) {
    line-height: 14px; }
  .nav-link:nth-child(6) {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 11px; }
  .nav-link:nth-child(7) {
    line-height: 11px; }
  .nav-link:nth-child(8) {
    line-height: 11px; }

.nav-link2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
<nav class="nav">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">главная</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">срочно продать <br>гараж</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">продать <br> машиноместо</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">продавцам и покупателям <br>услуги сопровождения<br> сделок</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">стоимость гаража <br> -оценка</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">риелторская<br> помощь <br>в покупке гаража</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">риелторская<br> помощьв <br>продаже гаража</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">оформить <br>гараж в <br>собственность</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">оформить <br>землю<br>под гагаржом<br></a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">ремонт <br> гаражей</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">прогноз рынка<br> гаражей и <br>паркингов</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">стоит ли продавать<br> гараж/<br>машиноместо?</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">выкуп<br> авто</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">займ<br> под <br>залог</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">видеоканал<br> -полезная <br>информация</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">вниманию <br>застройщиков</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">управление <br>гск</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link2">контакты</a>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут конечно не бутстрап, но может так?

```css
a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
 
body {
  margin:0;
  background-color:darkblue;
}

.l1 {
  line-height: 34px;
}

.l2 {
  line-height: 17px;
}

.l3 {
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a href="#" class="l1">главная</a>
  <a href="#" class="l2">срочно продать <br>гараж</a>
  <a href="#" class="l2">продать <br> машиноместо</a>
  <a href="#" class="l3">продавцам и покупателям <br>услуги сопровождения<br> сделок</a>
  <a href="#" class="l2">стоимость гаража <br> -оценка</a>
  <a href="#" class="l3">риелторская<br> помощь <br>в покупке гаража</a>
  <a href="#" class="l3">риелторская<br> помощьв <br>продаже гаража</a>
  <a href="#" class="l3">оформить <br>гараж в <br>собственность</a>
  <a href="#" class="l3">оформить <br>землю<br>под гагаржом</a>
  <a href="#" class="l2">ремонт <br> гаражей</a>
  <a href="#" class="l2">прогноз рынка<br> гаражей и <br>паркингов</a>
  <a href="#" class="l3">стоит ли продавать<br> гараж/<br>машиноместо?</a>
  <a href="#" class="l2">выкуп<br> авто</a>
  <a href="#" class="l3">займ<br> под <br>залог</a>
  <a href="#" class="l3">видеоканал<br>-полезная<br>информация</a>
  <a href="#" class="l2">вниманию <br>застройщиков</a>
  <a href="#" class="l2">управление <br>гск</a>
  <a href="#" class="l1">контакты</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте это будет адаптивно ?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Вы можете проверить - запустив сниппет и меняя размер окна браузера

Comment: простите не хотел Вас обидеть :((

Comment: @Leks через чат сложно понять эмоции, Вы меня не разу не обидели, да и не место тут для обид, я просто Вам подсказываю :) не берите в голову

Comment: спасибо что не обиделись,  а кто будет мне подсказывать :))

Comment: если возникнут проблемы Вам можно будет написать пожалуйста ?

Comment: скажите пожалуйста как лучше тут убрать отступы (margin) между кнопками

Comment: @Leks нужно убрать пробелы в разметке между `<a>..</a>`

Comment: спасибо добрая фея :)) P.S. я понял как работает код по js который мы обсуждали

Comment: убрал пробелы что-то не ничего не получилось может попробовать свойство white-space ?

Comment: пытаюсь прописать тег br после кнопки оформить гараж в собственность а перехода на новую строку нету

Comment: @Leks я что-то не догнал

Comment: там же вылазиют слова ..из меню

Comment: @MaximLensky классы не правильно расставил

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #3B4F73;
}
nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}
nav a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #333;
  background: #F9F8F8;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
   <a href="#">главная</a>
   <a href="#">срочно продать гараж</a>
   <a href="#">продать  машиноместо</a>
   <a href="#">продавцам и покупателям услуги сопровождения сделок</a>
   <a href="#">стоимость гаража  -оценка</a>
   <a href="#">риелторская помощь в покупке гаража</a>
   <a href="#">риелторская помощьв продаже гаража</a>
   <a href="#">оформить гараж в собственность</a>
   <a href="#">оформить землюпод гагаржом</a>
   <a href="#">ремонт  гаражей</a>
   <a href="#">прогноз рынка гаражей и паркингов</a>
   <a href="#">стоит ли продавать гараж/машиноместо?</a>
   <a href="#">выкуп авто</a>
   <a href="#">займ под залог</a>
   <a href="#">видеоканал -полезная информация</a>
   <a href="#">вниманию застройщиков</a>
   <a href="#">управление гск</a>
   <a href="#">контакты</a>
  </nav> 
</body>
</html>
```